# How to classify SAR image pixel by pixel in python using libsvm?

Tags: python, libsvm

I have extracted a pixel by pixel texture feature (dimension 45) from a SAR image. I have 4 ground truth images for 4 different classes (water, vegetation, urban, grassland). 
How do I add true class labels to the corresponding feature vector for training? I want to use LIBSVM for classification in python.